# My ionic3 code prompts for these errors when making an http request

Tags: angular, ionic3

If my http post request does not add the body parameter, then the request is completely normal; but when the body parameter is added; the following error will be prompted:

> Failed to load https://clk528.com/api/article: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, http://127.0.0.1:8100', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

[image]

My http service code:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {tap, catchError} from "rxjs/operators";
import {of} from "rxjs/observable/of";
import {Events} from "ionic-angular";

@Injectable()

export class HttpService {
    constructor(public http: HttpClient, private event: Events) {
    }

    public get<T>(url: string): Observable<T> {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        return this.http.get<T>(url, {headers: headers}).pipe(
            tap(model => console.log(model)),
            catchError(this.handleError<T>(url))
        );
    }

    public post<T>(url: string, body: any = null): Observable<T> {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        return this.http.post<T>(url, body, {
            headers: headers
        }).pipe(
            tap(model => console.log(model)),
            catchError(this.handleError<T>(url))
        );
    }

    private handleError<T>(operation = "operation", result?: T) {
        return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
            if (error.status) {
                switch (error.status) {
                    case 401:
                        this.event.publish("user::unautherized");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
            console.error(error, operation, result); // log to console instead
            // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
            return of(result as T);
        };
    }
}
```

If I use the following code to make a request, there is no error; and it can be done; my server will also return data.

```
this.http.post('https://clk528.com/api/article')
```

But when I add the parameters, it will describe the error generated above.

```
this.http.post('https://clk528.com/api/article', {
    page: 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) error. I am not sure why passing a body in a post request causes this error. Your error suggests that multiple origins are allowed to access server but server is allowing only one origin to access it, by origin, I mean a device in a way. One solution you may try is to remove 'http://127.0.0.1:8100' from you allowed origin list on the server and only allow '*' as an allowed origin.